# Stored Procedure - getting an error on the 2nd call

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Good Morning.
I'm VERY new to SQL and having an issue with stored procedures.  First off I'm using SQL 2008, I don't know if that makes a difference.  So here is my issue.  I call a stored procedure, 2 times in a row with different values being passed in.  (BTW, I just added the `with recompile` part.  It doesn't help)

```
EXECUTE crstored.sp_hhcAllActivityInstreamLoop
            @measureVarIDName ='staticPayact6moID'
            ,@measureSuppVarIDName ='payact6moID'
            ,@measureDesc ='payact6moDesc'
            ,@measureSuppTable ='crsupp.payact6mo'
            WITH RECOMPILE;
            GO

EXECUTE crstored.sp_hhcAllActivityInstreamLoop
            @measureVarIDName ='staticJourneyID'
            ,@measureSuppVarIDName ='journeyID'
            ,@measureDesc ='journeyDesc'
            ,@measureSuppTable ='crsupp.journey'
            WITH RECOMPILE;
            GO
```

The first time I call it, it will run.  The second time I get the following:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Invalid column name
>   'staticJourneyID'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Invalid column
>   name 'staticJourneyID'.

In order to fix it, I delete the stored procedure.  Recompile it half way, so it does nothing but bring in the parameters and do a simple select with one of the parameters.  Run it.  Delete the stored procedure.  Recompile the full procedure.  Then I can run it for the 2nd call.  However, now it is only set up to run for the JourneyID stuff, and if I have to go back and call it for the payAct6mos variables, I have to run thru the same delete, recompile, run scenario.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  The only thing I can think of right now is to have two copies of the same code, with different names.  I'd hate to have to maintain that.

Also, I don't know if it makes a difference, but because of how I'm using the parameters, I was told to enclose my code in the stored procedures with:

```
select @sqlcode=@sqlcode+'      type line of code here     '
```

Thanks!

---

Just a followup to my issue.  I figured it out.  Like I said, I'm just a novice in SQL.  So, turns out the tables I was dropping, I was dropping using dynamic SQL in the SP.  As soon as I dropped them using "regular" SQL, the calls ran fine.  I'm not sure why that is, but there you have it.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: show us the stored procedure code.

Comment: So, I can't post the SP because it's too many characters.

Answer (score 4):

This is speculation.  My best guess is that the second part of the stored procedure is using dynamic SQL.  It is constructing a SQL statement using the name in `@measureVarIDName`.

The column `staticPayact6moID` exists in the table it is looking at.

The column `staticJourneyID` does not exist in the table.

In other words, you need to fix the first argument (at least) in the second call.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I am using dynamic SQL and I use the parameters to create some code.  Does it mean it's keeping something in cache because once I recompile the SP, I can run the call the SP with staticJourneyID without any issues.

Comment: @user2370154 . . . No.  In my experience, stored procedure arguments work pretty well.  You'll need to post the code for the stored procedure for any more guidance.  One other thing . . . Include the name of the database in the stored procedure call, just to be sure the same code is being called each time.